# Upload html in Django

Tags: django

Code in template:

```
<form action="/html/" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <input type="file" id="html_file" name="html_file" />
    <input type="submit" value="Upload" />
</form>
```

and in view

```
def add_html(request):
    if request.POST:
        #do something with html
        return redirect('/')
    else:
        return render_to_response('add_html.html')
```

I need to html-file is loaded and read its contents, not upload to the server.
But I get an error:

> csrf token missing or incorrect

How fix?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My guess is that the `{% csrf_token %}` is empty when your template is rendered.

Per the [CSRF documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/csrf/#how-to-use-it) you should use the [render](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/topics/http/shortcuts/#django.shortcuts.render) function instead of the render_to_response function to ensure the RequestContext, which includes the csrf_token, is properly loaded into your template.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve what you want with the following code:

**forms.py:**

```
from django import forms


class ReadFileForm(forms.Form):
    file = forms.FileField()
```

**views.py:**

```
from .forms import ReadFileForm


def read_file(request):
    form = ReadFileForm()
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = ReadFileForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            content = request.FILES['file'].read()
            # Do something with content
    return render(request, 'read_file.html', locals())
```

**templates/read_file.html:**

```
<html>
    <head></head>
    <body>
        <h3>Read File Content</h3>
        <form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="" method="post">
            {% csrf_token %}
            {{ form }}
            <input type="submit" value="Save">
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Why do you think that you need to create a form?

Comment: I think this is the cleanest way to implement it, and `csrf_token` is automatically available in your template.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. Really, a good option. But for my case, felt no need to create a separate form page will be solely for their own use.